# VsDevCmd vs VsMSBuildCmd

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

What's the difference between `VsDevCmd.bat` and `VsMSBuildCmd.bat` in Visual Studio 2015 (CTP 5)?

Both located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools` aka `VS140COMNTOOLS`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for `VsMSBuildCmd.bat`, it sets `VS140COMNTOOLS` environment variable from the registry, and also adds MSBuild in the `PATH`.

`VsDevCmd.bat` does the same plus it adds a bunch of other directories in the `PATH` and sets a few more environment variables, most of which are used by Visual C++ compiler. Also adds path to TypeScript Compiler.

Comment: Why does `VsDevCmd.bat` initialize an environment for `x86`? How could one have an `x64` environment?

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170#developer_command_file_locations, VsDevCmd.bat defaults to the x86 tools. You can use vcvars64.bat to explicitly request x64 tools.